# Jumping navigation bar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is quite complex (difficult to explain at least).

I have a responsive navigation bar that is by default NOT on the top of the page but you have to scroll down a bit for the navbar to reach the top of the browser window.

On desktop (48em<) one can simply scroll through the navbar (so it simply disappears when scrolling down) but when scrolling back up, it gets a "sticky" class (thanks to JS) and appears on top.

On mobile, the navbar gets sticky once the scroll position reaches the navbar element.

My problem is with the mobile view. I had to add a piece of CSS code so that the page content won't flicker (jump) when scrolling down. (I only need it when the sticky class is added by JS.)

```
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 58px;
}
```

Which works just fine when the hamburger menu is CLOSED.

When the menu is opened, the navbar's height changes and it requires more padding on top for it not to make the page content jump. See the gif below.

[image: With padding-top: 58px]

If I change this padding to 248px then the content doesn't jump when the menu is opened, but it jumps when it's closed. ‍♂️

```
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 248px;
}
```

[image: With padding-top: 248px]

I guess I should write a piece of JS code that would do this:

- If nav checkbox is checked then change .sticky + .content {padding-top: 248px;}
- If it's unchecked change it back to .sticky + .content {padding-top: 58px;}
- All this only below 48em. On desktop the padding is supposed to be 0.

Here's a fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/t0zLv7yn/48/

I don't know much about JS so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the `padding-top`.. Actually you shouldn't manipulate your `sticky` class. CSS `position: sticky` does for you all the job automatically. You have to fix 3 things:

1. You don't need to toggle `.sticky` class on scroll.. You have to **remove** this code:

```
// You don't need this all
if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
  header.classList.add("sticky");
} else {
  header.classList.remove("sticky");
}
```

2. you permanently **add** class `sticky` to the `header`

```
<header class="header sticky" id="navbar">
```

3. You **remove**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sticky {
  /* position: fixed; You don't need this */
  }
}
```

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tyminko/coetd4jx/1/

Answer (score 1):

The modern answer to you problem is to position submenu with absolute.

```
.big-wrapper-main {
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Submenu positioned that way doesn't change the height of the parent, is positioned after it (because of top: 100% - 100% stands for 100% height of the parent).

The problem is that you are using `float` and `clear` and we don't do it in web development for the while now and the height of your `.big-wrapper-main` is `0px` so you have to add position relative to `#navbar` (when it is not fixed).

I had to add .header.sticky to overwrite position relative.

```
.header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! So the menu would be above the other layers. It's also a good solution, thank you, I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: But wait, there's one thing I cannot understand. What is "main"?
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: white;
}

Can you please add a fiddle?

Comment: @ZsoltSzilvai sorry, you are right the right name of this class is ".menu" not main.